# MySQL SELECT join 3 tables with conditions for all rows

Tags: mysql, join

I need some help to create my select correctly...

Here is my tables :

```
**teacher** :
id
name

**classroom** :
id
teacher_id

**students** :
id
name
classroom_id
status
```

I am trying to select all the teachers that have a classroom. 
Classroom may be selected only if ALL students have a status > 10...

If a student has a status 5 for example the classroom may NOT be selected and therefore the teacher may NOT be selected (besides he has a another OK classroom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
select * from teacher t
inner join classroom c on t.id=c.teacher_id
inner join 
(select * from students 
group by classroom_id having classroom_id not in 
(select distinct classroom_id from students where status<=10)) s 
on s.classroom_id=c.id
```

updated : 
from your comment i think query above should work but you can test this query :

```
select * from teacher t where id in
   (select distinct teacher_id from classroom where id in
       (select distinct classroom_id from students 
        group by classroom_id having classroom_id not in 
          (select distinct classroom_id from students where status<=10)
        )
    )
```

Comment: hmm you need create some index or view to make performance better but for query, its the best i can think for now.. Please accept if your question answered :)

Comment: So you mean if one classroom not ok then you want exclude that teacher from list? if yes we need to adjust query a bit..

Comment: if the teacher has 2 classrooms, one ok and one not ok... This teacher must be selected... sorry

Comment: try my updated query.. first query should be works... but you can test second query as well... `selected` mean included to list??